# Moved site to 1&1 hosting, but is broken and redirecting to GoDaddy 404

Tags: 404-error, migration, hosting

I'm actually just trying to mirror a GoDaddy site on a subdirectory of my personal 1&1 hosting.

I just strait up copy-pasted the file structure, and copied the Database, using a [search replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace the base url with my new one. I then editted the wp-config with the new DB stuff.

When I navigate to http://oneandone.com/wp for some reason its redirecting me to a GoDaddy 404 page.

If I go to http://oneandone.com/wp/readme.html it displays the appropriate file correctly.

In the options table in the db, I've verified that the siteurl is correct.

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Anyone have any insight?

**Update**

It may be of interest, that the problem persists even when wp-config has bad info for the database.  I think this indicates that wp-config isn't even loading.  The index.php file looks normal, as well as the .htaccess, so I'm totally at a loss here.

**Update 2**

http://oneandone.com/wp/index.php brings me to the expected Database Error page.  Where http://oneandone.com/wp/ gets the godaddy 404 page.

**FINAL UPDATE:  PROBLEM RESOLVED**

[see my answer below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61156/5846)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm a jerk.  Somehow I overlooked the welcome.html file in the root of the wp install (for some reason this is a GoDaddy 404 page).  Not sure what code is causing that to load instead of index.php, but there it is.  I deleted this file, and voila!  Everything works as expected.  That was a waste of 6 hours haha.

Comment: lol :) happens , good thing you found it. It was quite confusing indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your .htaccess file is correct.
did you copy that aswell?

Comment: I checked that, everything looks kosher - same as a new install

Comment: so to get this straight, example.com is 1&1 hosting yes? 
maybe call it oneone.com or something to keep it more clear. 

maybe there is more than one .htaccess? you have one in folder aswell? 

maybe you can use chrome's devtools and check the timeline see what happens. 
you know how to do that?

Comment: I'll change that naming convention now, I can see how that would be confusing.  

I'm starting to think maybe "redirect" was not the correct word to use.  Timeline shows the first item as a request to http://oneone.com/wp/ - and this resource is the godaddy 404 page.  If that makes sense.  I just have no idea where its coming from and why.